# Having Single and SingleOrDefault to throw a more succinct exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, design-patterns

When invoking `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable<T>`, and it has more than one result, it throws `InvalidOperationException`.

While the actual message of the exception is very descriptive, it is problematic to write a catch that will only handle the cases where the `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` calls fail.

```
public virtual Fee GetFeeByPromoCode(string promoCode)
{
    try
    {
        return _fees.SingleOrDefault(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode));
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw new TooManyFeesException();
    }
}
```

In this scenario, if `IsPromoCodeValid` also throws an `InvalidOperationException`, then it becomes ambiguous as to what the catch is handling.

I *could* inspect the message of the exception, but I would like to avoid that as I find it dirty to handle code depending on a message of an exception.

My current alternative to the `SingleOrDefault` looks like the following:

```
public virtual Fee GetFeeByPromoCode(string promoCode)
{
    var fees = _fees.Where(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode)).ToList();

    if (fees.Count > 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidFeeSetupException();
    }

    return fees.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However, this code is a lot less obvious than the code above, in addition, this generates a less efficient query (if using a linq-enabled ORM) than using `SingleOrDefault`.

I could also do a `Take(2)` with my second example to optimize it a bit, but this further obfuscates the intent of the code.

Is there a way to do this without writing my own extension for both `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`?

Comment: Perhaps have `IsPromoCode` throw a custom exception? Interesting question though.

Comment: Have you considered creating a well-named extension method that does your `take(2)` method?

Comment: `I could also do a Take(2) with my second example to optimize it a bit, but this further obfuscates the intent of the code.` - IMO, `Take(2)` with the check `fees.Count > 1` makes it more clear

Comment: Keep in mind IQueryable is IEnumberable  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: Why are you not using FirstOrDefault directly?   _fees.FirstOrDefault(fee => fee.IsPromoCodeValid("PromoCode"));  You don't really need the method GetFeeByPromoCode

Comment: @user3444160 I want to make sure there is only zero or one valid promo codes.

Comment: @Habib The `Take(2)` is what `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` essentially do when using `IQueryable` providers.

Comment: What's the logic behind IsPromoCodeValid() throwing InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @Ian not sure, it's 3rd party code that I don't have access to change.

Comment: if you want it to throw an exception when _fees contains more than one fee of the same value, use Single instead of SingleOrDefault.  _fees.Single(fee => fee.IsPromoCodeValid("PromoCode"));  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using exceptions in this way is bad design pattern. Exceptions should always caused by exceptional situations and not used for normal programming design. Two situations occur - one is that you can't tell what the program flow is by looking at the method signatures - second if you forget to catch an exception it can bubble up to a higher catch block and cause your program to fail. You should always handle "too many fees" through normal code, not exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this solve the problem?

```
public virtual Fee GetFeeByPromoCode(string promoCode)
{
    try
    {
        return _fees.SingleOrDefault(f =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode);
                }
                catch(InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    throw new PromoCodeException();
                }
            });
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw new TooManyFeesException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to be able to modify the Exception messages and I did this using extension with normal string parameters (see first extension method below),

your solution I used a  generic extension to make it nice and clean. I passed the Exception Types to be thrown as generic types (see second extension method below).

I decompiled the System.Linq.Enumerable library and copied their code and just modified the exception messages and exceptions types to be thrown, here we go!

New linq Extensions:

```
  public static class LinqExtentions
  {        
    // Extension method 1 : Just to change the message for the "more than one" exception
    public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string moreThanOneMatchMessage = "MoreThanOneMatch")
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            switch (list.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    return default(TSource);
                case 1:
                    return list[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return default(TSource);
                }
                TSource current = enumerator.Current;
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        // I Changed this line below from their code - moreThanOneMatchMessage as parameter
        // It was : throw Error.MoreThanOneElement(); in other words it was throw new InvalidOperationException("MoreThanOneMatch");
        throw new InvalidOperationException(moreThanOneMatchMessage);
    }

    // Extension method 2 : Change the Exception Type to be thrown and the message
    public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource, TMoreThanOnceExceptionType>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string noElementsMessage = "NoElements", string moreThanOneMatchMessage = "MoreThanOneMatch")
       where TMoreThanOnceExceptionType : Exception
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            switch (list.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    return default(TSource);
                case 1:
                    return list[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return default(TSource);
                }
                TSource current = enumerator.Current;
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        // Changes this line below to throw dynamic exception type.
        // It was : throw Error.MoreThanOneElement(); in other words it was throw new InvalidOperationException("MoreThanOneMatch");
        // Yes some believe the Activator can slow down code, If you use a DI Framework and register your exception type this should not be the case
        throw (TMoreThanOnceExceptionType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TMoreThanOnceExceptionType), moreThanOneMatchMessage);
    }
}
```

OK, and here is the usage code:

```
    public static void TestMethod(string promoCode)
    {
        List<Fee> promoCodes = new List<Fee>();
        // Add promo codes in for example

        // moreThanOneMatchMessage = "Duplicate Promo codes detected" and retur null for no codes
        promoCodes
            .Where(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode))
            .SingleOrDefault(moreThanOneMatchMessage: "Duplicate Promo codes detected");

        // OR noElementsMessage = "There is no Promotion codes configured" and moreThanOneMatchMessage = "Duplicate Promo codes!!"
        // This extention was not included in the code section, wanted to keep response small however show this extention, same concept as SingleOrDefault extention
        promoCodes
            .Where(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode))
            .Single(moreThanOneMatchMessage: "Duplicate Promo codes!!", noElementsMessage: "There is no Promotion codes configured");

        try
        {
            // Lets Customeze the exception type, TooManyFeesException thrown with a message "Duplicate Promo codes!!"
            // AND if there are no items a InvlaidArgumentException with message "There is no Promotion codes configured"
            promoCodes
                    .Where(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode))
                    .SingleOrDefault<Fee, TooManyFeesException>("There is no Promotion codes configured", "Duplicate Promo codes!!");
        }
        catch (TooManyFeesException tmte)
        {
            //catching you specific exception here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would even be better with a FormattableString as argument/overload to defer the formatting of the string.

Answer (score 2):

I consider First() / Single() / SingleOrDefault() as a kind of Assert.

i.e. If you use them you don't want to catch the exception. Something is very wrong with your data and it should be handled as a critical error.

If multiple results is normal in your model, don't use exceptions to verify it.

From that perspective I don't think your Take(2) version is less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidOperationException` is rather general. Any of the properties accessed (or even deeper in the stack) could throw this exception. Therefor, one way is to roll your own exception and extension method. For example:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static TSource ExactlyOneOrZero<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
        if (predicate == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate"); }

        IEnumerable<TSource> matchingItems = source.Where(predicate);
        IReadOnlyList<TSource> limitedMatchingItems = matchingItems.Take(2).ToList();

        int matchedItemCount = limitedMatchingItems.Count;

        switch (matchedItemCount)
        {
            case 0: return default(TSource);
            case 1: return limitedMatchingItems[0]; // Or Single() 
            default: throw new TooManyMatchesException();
        }
    }
}

class TooManyMatchesException : Exception { /* Don't forget to implement this properly. */ }
```

This enables you to keep the original code clean:

```
    public virtual Fee GetFeeByPromoCode(string promoCode)
    {
        try
        {
            return _fees.ExactlyOneOrZero(f => f.IsPromoCodeValid(promoCode));
        }
        catch (TooManyMatchesException)
        {
            throw new TooManyFeesException();
        }
    }
```

Another way to do this, is to use the `TryGet...`-pattern, but it's not very clean. The `TryGetSingle` would return true even if there are no matching elements. You could replace the boolean by an enum (Valid/Invalid), but I'll leave it up to the reader whether this is readable or not.